# How to get inner values from XML

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml, linq

I have an xml as shown below,in that i want to get second `SubNetwork` element value and `tval` value,so here first row values are `NC22` and `tet_DS_U_6359_HolidayExpressInKV`.I did following prtial  code as shown below,how to get the second `SubNetwork` and `tval` values for each  rows which finally i will put in to dictionery where `tval` is key.This is big XML of few GB size ,,and i posted a small part

```
(XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(path))
{
    string sitename = "";
    xr.MoveToContent();
    XNamespace xn = xr.LookupNamespace("tn");
    while (xr.Read())
    {
        while (xr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && xr.NamespaceURI == tn && xr.LocalName == "mentNode" && xr.GetAttribute("id") == "TRM")
        {
            try
            {
                XElement sniipet = (XElement)XNode.ReadFrom(xr);
                var xdoc = new XDocument(sniipet);
                var orders = (from r in xdoc.Descendants(tn + "manages")
                              select new
                              {


                              }).ToList();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

and XML is as shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<tn:mentNode id="TRM">
  <tn:attributes>
    <tn:manages>SubNetwork=TRM_R,SubNetwork=NC22,tval=tet_DS_U_6359_HolidayExpressInKV,Element=1</tn:manages>
    <tn:manages>SubNetwork=TRM_R,SubNetwork=NC22,tval=tet_DS_U_6352_MediaOneHtl,Element=1</tn:manages>
  </tn:attributes>
</tn:mentNode>
```

**EDIT**

Though XML is big `<tn:mentNode id="TRM">` node is not that much big which i can hold in dictionery

Comment: So you've got some code already - what happens? (I suspect I can guess, but it's quite tricky as we don't know which URI the namespace alias "tn" is associated with.) I'd also strongly advise you to remove that empty catch block, or at least change it to log. If there's an error, you *probably* want to stop processing at that point, and you almost *certainly* want to know about it rather than silently ignoring it.

Comment: i am writing log properly,this is small test code i posted here

Comment: Empty `catch` clause — worst error handling ever.

Comment: i already told ,this is test code and XML is test  XML which is of size 5GB,i am writing custom log in catch block

Comment: Though XML is big <tn:mentNode id="TRM"> node is not that much big which i can hold in dictionery

Comment: Are you sure that second `while` loop shouldn't just be an `if`?  Also are you just asking about how to parse the string data in the XML or are you having issues with the XML reading?

Comment: i am parsing XML of size 5GB and getting a small part of node <tn:mentNode id="TRM">, so this code i am using otherwise out of memory will throw

Comment: Why are you repeatedly telling us it's a large file.  We get it and totally understand why you're using a XmlReader to handle it.  What I personal don't understand is what your actual question/problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use just XDocument instead of XmlReader :

```
            XDocument xr = XDocument.Load(path);

            List<string> orders = xr.Descendants().Where(x => (x.Name.LocalName == "mentNode") && ((string)x.Attribute("id") == "TRM"))
                .Select(x => x.Descendants().Where(y => y.Name.LocalName == "manages").Select(y => (string)y))
                .SelectMany(x => x).ToList();
```